# Imagine an unordered list of multidimensional domino stones, where each pair of dominos is unique. How to elegantly and efficiently solve dominos?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

As a software developer for geometry algorithms I ran into the following problem a few times already never really satisfies with how I solved it.

#### The problem statement

Imagine dominos in the 3D-cartesian space with the faces holding 3D-coordinates `(x, y, z)`. An additional condition to this game is, that each coordinate exists only once in the game and is written on exactely the faces of **two** stones. A pair of dominos is found once one finds a matching pair of faces. A path is defined as an ordered list of dominos where each two pairwise adjacent elements (dominos) in the list form a match. There can be multiple paths in one game of domino.

#### Examples

An example would look as follows before and after playing the sorting game:

Game 1: Single path as an outcome.
[image: Dominos with 3D-coordinates. Each 3D-coordinate only exists once as a pair.]

Game 2: Multiple paths as an outcome.
[image: A game can have multiple paths as an outcome.]

Is there a a) efficient and b) elegant solution to this problem?

#### Naive solution with while-loop

My best guess is something as follows:

```
Let the input list of dominos be called list.
Let the currently forming path be an ordered list called cur_path.
Let the resulting list of paths be called results.

While (list is not empty)
  If (cur_path is empty)
    Draw random piece of domino from list and put into cur_path.
    Continue
  Else
    // Search equals finding a match for open ends of cur_path,
    // i.e. the first and the last domino in cur_path.
    Search in list for matching domino
    If (Found matching domino)
      Draw found piece from list and put at correct position into cur_path
    Else
      // We have not found a match amongst all residual dominos.
      // Store current path into result paths and begin new.
      Store cur_path in results.
      Clear variable cur_path.
      Continue

return results
```

You will see that I while-loop over all elements in approx. O(n²). There are two approaches to this solution that I do not like. First, I do not like while-loops as they are always bound on conditions which does not feel deterministic. Second, I dont like how I neglect the geometric information of the dominos to narrow down the search space for matches. Do you think a sorted hierarchy like a bounding-volume hierarchy approach would be too overkill to solve this?

Comment: Can you make a drawing of some of those "multidimensional dominoes"?

Comment: I uploaded an example. Does it clarify my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solvable in `O(n)`.

Here is untested Python:

```py
    tiles_at = {} # will map coordinates to tiles.
    for tile in all_tiles:
        for face in tile.faces:
            if face not in tiles_at:
                tiles_at[face] = [tile]
            else:
                tiles_at[face].append(tile)

    is_used = set() # will hold the used tiles
    paths = [] # will hold the final answer. Does not find loops.
    for face, tiles in tiles_at.items():
        if 1 == len(tiles) and tiles[0] not in is_used:
            # Found the start of a path.
            is_used.add(tiles[0])
            last_face = face
            last_tile = tiles[0]
            if face != tiles[0].faces[0]:
                last_tile = last_tile.flip()
            path = [last_tile]

            # Find the path
            while True:
                # Find the unused face.
                last_face = last_tile.faces[1]

                # Find the next tile in the path, if any.
                if 1 == len(tiles_at[last_face]):
                    break # EXIT LOOP AT END OF PATH
                elif last_tile == tiles_at[last_face][0]:
                    last_tile = tiles_at[last_face][1]
                else:
                    last_tile = tiles_at[last_face][0]
                # We used this tile
                is_used.add(last_tile)
                if last_face == last_tile.faces[1]:
                    last_tile = last_tile.flip()
                path.append(last_tile)
        # and record the path
        paths.append(path)
```

The idea is a `O(n)` scan to add all faces of tiles to a hash.  An `O(n)` scan to find all possible starting points, and for each starting point a scan of the path that will, over all paths, visit every one of `O(n)` tiles exactly once.

Which, combined, is `O(n)`.

Comment: That is actually a very neat simplification to the problem. Thanks for your solution! I realized that it would be working with my actual programming problem, if the values of my faces would be of an integer type. Unfortunately they are of a floating type. But as it was not stated in my question, I will gladly accept this excellent answer.

Comment: @Nevsden Ah, well you can stick the faces into a k-d tree and match them up that way?

Comment: That sounds feasible. I will try it out! Still undecided however what would be the most suitable value for the item size in the leaf nodes.

Comment: There is a problem with the idea in general. The tile faces do not always match perfectly and need to be tested for relative equality rather than absolute. This is due to the fact, that the faces are computed on a computer with floating-point arithmetic. The k-d tree works for narrowing down the number of faces to be checked for relative equality, however.